# Get Facebook Video Thumbnails Large Size using Facebook Video ID - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Hello I have checked many Stackoverflow questions regarding this. Following is the list of questions which I have seen:

1. [Get Facebook video thumbnail image URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848195/get-facebook-video-thumbnail-image-urls)
2. [How to get Facebook video thumbnail from its video id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000856/how-to-get-facebook-video-thumbnail-from-its-video-id)
3. [How to get big facebook video thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773155/how-to-get-big-facebook-video-thumbnail)
4. [How to get facebook video thumbnail from a given video ID using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155110/how-to-get-facebook-video-thumbnail-from-a-given-video-id-using-php)
5. [Get large facebook video thumbnail using graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398557/get-large-facebook-video-thumbnail-using-graph)

But I got answer from no where.

I used this: `https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture`, it worked but giving me very small thumbnail.

Please help me if you have got any way for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check /videoid/thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

I find how get thumbnail high solution using and i success get thumbnail high solution. You can using bellow code:

```
$video_id= Input::get('id_video');
$config = [
    'app_id' => \Config::get('setting.APP_ID'),
    'app_secret' => \Config::get('setting.SECRET_ID'),
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.7',
];

$fb = new Facebook($config);

$accessToken = Input::get('access_token');


$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$video_id."?fields=description,thumbnails&access_token=".$accessToken;
//Make the API call
$result = file_get_contents($url);
//Decode the JSON result.
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
//Dump it out onto the page so that we can take a look at the structure of the data.
var_dump($decoded);
```

$accessToken I get from Graph explorer tool, Or you code function login facebook you can get access_token.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

I Hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

Same you, I using Graph explorer can get thumbnails video but I cant get thumbnails from "https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture". You can refe follow

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{video-id}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```